# Premature close(Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client) error while streaming video in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm building a video streaming web server using Nestjs.

I followed the exact same way introduced in [nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files).

However, there are some errors...

#### MY file.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, StreamableFile, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
@Controller('file')
export class FileController {
    @Get()
    getOne(@Response({ passthrough: true }) res): StreamableFile {
        const file = createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), 'sampleVideo.mp4'));
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        });
        return new StreamableFile(file);
    }
}
```

#### Error code

```
[Nest] 21224  - 2022. 08. 02. 4:41:16   ERROR [ExpressAdapter] Premature close
Error: Premature close
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.onclose (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:142:30)
    at ServerResponse.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at Socket.onServerResponseClose (node:_http_server:236:23)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\whan9\mvp-backend-nestjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\whan9\mvp-backend-nestjs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at StreamableFile.handleError (C:\Users\whan9\mvp-backend-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\common\file-stream\streamable-file.js:14:17)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\whan9\mvp-backend-nestjs\node_modules\@nestjs\platform-express\adapters\express-adapter.js:43:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
```

#### Environment

```
Windows 10
node version: v16.16.0
npm: 8.15.1
```

The `sampleVideo.mp4` is OK. It exist in the right place.

If I get rid of `res.set({'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'});`, the video stream data is downloaded without errors, but also any filename extension.

I want to know what I'm missing...

Comment: What is the file size of samplevideo.mp4? Did you try piping the streams to response like,
```file.pipe(res)``` ?

Comment: @vicki the size of sampleVideo.mp4 is about 15MB. 
If I add file.pipe(res), It surely works. But I want to make the Nestjs framework take care of piping the file, so that I can add the post-controller interceptor logic later. StreamableFile class helps to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For the Set Headers Error. In NestJS's documentation on [Streaming Files](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) it uses the **@Res** decorator instead of **@Response**. It probably is just an alias, but it's the only difference I can find in your code to the docs and my implementation.

The Premature close error happens because the request is somehow being cancelled quickly before it can even start sending the stream. As of [August 16, 2022](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/10106) NestJS is now catching this Premature error so that it no longer crashes de server.